# WinJS SnapPoints: ms-scroll-snap-type mandatory won't reach the end with mousewheel or touch

Tags: css, windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

I'm testing out some snap points on a flexbox on WinJS for Windows 8.1 and everything works fine except for the fact that when using either touch or the mouse wheel (in the simulator) to scroll the list horizontally I can't reach the last items in the list unless I physically use the scrollbar to reach it.

Here is the CSS:

```
.testFlexbox {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    overflow: auto;
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0, 350px);
}
```

Here is an image illustrating the issue:

[image]

I assume its because the width of the testFlexbox does not divide exactly by 350px? The reason I'm using interval over step is because the number of items inside the flexbox is likely to change.

I'm using a repeater for the list of items not a listview just in case that helps.

I wondered if anyone knows of a way around this as there isn't a huge amount of documentation available online regarding the subject.

Many thanks for your help

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think what is important there is that you leave a little padding (usually 80px) in the win-surface class, and no padding in the win-vieport class.

The surface scroll under the viewport. 
The latter is the mask over the first, so it need a little bit of space to get to the end of it.

Have a look at what I am talking about here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh850406.aspx

Comment: I should probably say, I'm using a repeater not a listview.

I tried your technique though and it gets me a little further just not all the way.

Comment: I guess the space you need to add it must be calculated and it must be  what is left to bring the total width to be a multiple of 350px (your interval)

Comment: also what is 350px? is it the width of those boxes? does it include the margin?

Comment: 350px is the total width from the left edge of one element to the left edge of another including the margin. thanks for the continued help.

Comment: so I guess the lenght of your viewport is 1050px?

Comment: Its variable depending on the resolution of he screen. Do I need to make it divisible by 350px as that seems a little inflexible?

Comment: I think it should. you items are always gonna be 350 and your interval is always gonna be 350, so I don't se any flexibility issue. Try it out anyway.

Comment: Thanks Maurizio, its just not very flexible but I shall try it and see how I get on.